# IES data files (as per IESNA LM-63-2002)

Tags: file, python-2.7

I'm trying to write software to perform calculations using the candlepower information stored in IES formatted data files (.ies extension, format as per IESNA LM-63-2002).  Has anyone developed a simple library for the input/output of this file type?